# Mark inside checkbox

Tags: css, javafx, checkbox

I have a short question. How can I change mark inside checkbox from standard tick to dot? I already have a circle shape. All I want is my checkbox looks like radiobutto. How can I solved this?

Comment: It's possible but from a UX perspective it would give the user an unexpected behaviour. Why don't use the "radio" attribute

Comment: @Ramesh Will that work with JavaFX?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you have done so far and where exactly you are stuck (you seem to be using css to change the shape, so you could do the same for the mark). But shouldn't ... you really dont want to confuse your users :)

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with [ProgrammerPer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3504096/programmerper) that this might not be a great idea from a user experience perspective, sometimes manipulations like this are necessary.

If I'm understanding the OP's question, I think the only way this could be accomplished is to mirror the checkbox functionality with a div (for example) so it can have a custom 'ticked' view.

This a great resource for customizing inputs: http://wtfforms.com/

Also, this post and the article linked in it, might be worth a read regarding the UX implications: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41924/is-it-acceptable-practice-to-use-checkboxes-as-radio-buttons

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.